# Compatibility Settings Inheritance

Tags: windows, compatibility

Hopefully, as always, this is the right place to post this question..

I have a quick question about the compatibility settings you apply to a program. A friend of mine said that the compatibility settings from one program will automatically be passed on to any program that this program starts.

This seems unlikely to me, but I thought I should atleast investigate it before saying it's not. After about 30 minutes I gave up searching because I couldn't find anything.

So, do they get passed on to other processes? -or is there any way to make sure that it does? -does it depends on which version of Windows is used?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatibility settings are not inherited. They are associated with individual executable files.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Short and sweet!